# How to incorporate XUL based plugin into an SDK based plugin?

Tags: xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a plugin build with the Addon SDK that manipulates HTTP requests and another one that manipulates the DOM but is build in the bootstrapped(XUL) way.
Basically I have to incorporate the bootstraped plugin into the SDK based plugin to combine their functionality but without making too many changes to the XUL based plugin.

Is there any way to this without a massive rewrite of any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrapped add-ons are very similar but far more chaotic, it'll be worth organizing your code if you plan to maintain it, and the sdk provides a sane test framework.

Answer (score 0):

Does the older add-on use overlays? If so, a lot of work will be required to programmatically add the UI to Firefox in a restartless add-on. This is true regardless of whether you use the SDK or not.

Comment: No. The bootstrapped plugin has no interface. It only makes changes in the DOM. I tried to use pagemod and integrate all that code into a contentscript but it uses XPCOM modules that I cannot pass into the content script for reference.. or I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: You can't pass xpcom stuff into a contetn script when using page-mod, instead you need to pass data between xpcom in main.js and the content script using message passing: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html